# Issues connecting R to HANA db with many special characters

Tags: r, odbc, hana

I am having issues with reading HANA data into R.

I have established my connection via

```
ch <- odbcConnect("HANA",uid="USER",pwd="PW")
```

And confirmed I am connected via

```
sqlTables(ch)
```

which pulls up my list of tables.

Filtering on my desired table I am trying to pull reveals the full name to be "ccf-edw.self-service.MDM::Q_CA_R_CUSTOMER_REPORTS"

From other posts I have seen, there appear to be issues surrounding the periods.

Attempting

```
sqlQuery(ch, 'SELECT TOP 10 FROM "_SYS_BIC"."ccf-edw"."self-service"."MDM::Q_CA_R_CUSTOMER_REPORTS"')
```

Returns error

```
[1] "42000 257 [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] Syntax error or access violation;257 sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near \"FROM\": line 1 col 15 (at pos 15)"
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT TOP 10 FROM \"_SYS_BIC\".\"ccf-edw\".\"self-service\".\"MDM::Q_CA_R_CUSTOMER_REPORTS\"'"
```

I am unsure exactly where to stick additional double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this instead:

```
sqlQuery(ch, 'SELECT TOP 10 FROM "_SYS_BIC"."ccf-edw.self-service.MDM::Q_CA_R_CUSTOMER_REPORTS"')
```

Comment: This works, but with replacing the "::" with a "/". It is only working with sqlQuery, not sqlFetch, what might be causing that? Fetch gives the error                                                                  `Error in odbcTableExists(channel, sqtable) : 
  ‘Select * FROM "_SYS_BIC"."ccf-edw.self-service.MDM/Q_CA_R_CUSTOMER_REPORTS’: table not found on channel`

Comment: As per the R doc, sqlQuery can be used to get data from a query whereas sqlFetch is only applicable to table names and not SQL queries.

see: 

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RODBC/versions/1.3-15/topics/sqlFetch

and

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RODBC/versions/1.3-15/topics/sqlQuery

Comment: I also recommend you to get table names from the TABLES view for you schema. This will give you the proper names.

Comment: Using sqlTables is where I got the original table name, the one with the two colons in it, not sure where the one with the slash between MDM and Q_CA_R come in.

Comment: Usually this names come from SAP HANA calculation views.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58491247/4808122) answer how to use both single and double quotes i the query string.