# R Pass required variable from ODBC/HANA connection to sql statement

Tags: sql, r, odbc, hana, rodbc

I have a table I am trying to call with my usual method

```
sql <- 'SELECT TOP 10 *
         FROM "_SYS_BIC"."data-path.self-service.DOIP/table_name"'

df <- dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, sql)
```

and receive the error

```
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for SELECT TOP 10 *
         FROM "_SYS_BIC"."data-path.self-service.DOIP/table_name" (SAP DBTech JDBC: [2048]: column store error: search table error:  [34023] Instantiation of calculation model failed;exception 306106: Undefined variable: $$IP_ExtractionWeekFrom$$. Variable is marked as required but not set in the query)
```

I've been trying to insert IP_ExtractionWeekFrom into the sql statement with a where clause with no luck

```
param1 <- 201943

sql <- 'SELECT TOP 10 *
         FROM "_SYS_BIC"."ccf-edw.self-service.DOIP/R_CA_B_DemandPlan" where
         "$$IP_ExtractionWeek$$" = ?'

SpringVisit <- dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, sql, param1)
```

I've tried the term surrounded by the "$$" and without, and both with and without "$$" sourrounded in quotes and not. Usually am met with an "invalid column name" error.

Is this supposed to be called with something other than a where clause?

Comment: Does that below query with hard-coded param value work in your SAP / hana console or IDE or workbench (i.e., outside of R)?

Comment: We don't have one per se. Prior to my joining most data were pulled through our Tableau/HANA connection, the sql for that shows up as                                                                 ````SELECT * FROM "ccf-edw.self-service.DOIP::Q_CA_B_DemandPlan" ( 'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_ExtractionWeekFrom$$', '201943'), 'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_ExtractionWeekTo$$', '201943') ) "ccf_edw_self_service_DOIP__Q_CA_B_DemandPlan"
WHERE (1 <> 0)````

Comment: Did you attempt that query in R? What was the result?

Comment: Sure did, syntax error ````param1 <- 201943
param2 <- 201943

sql <- 'SELECT TOP 10 *
         FROM "_SYS_BIC"."ccf-edw.self-service.DOIP/R_CA_B_DemandPlan" ( "PLACEHOLDER" = ("$$IP_ExtractionWeekFrom$$", ?), "PLACEHOLDER" = ("$$IP_ExtractionWeekTo$$", ?) ) "_SYS_BIC"."ccf-edw.self-service.DOIP/R_CA_B_DemandPlan" WHERE (1 <> 0)'

SpringVisit <- dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, sql, param1, param2) 

(SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near """: line 2 col 91 (at pos 107))````

Comment: Why are you double quoting `"PLACEHOLDER"` and `"$$IP_ExtractionWeekTo$$"`? Double quotes means a specific thing in SQL and is not interchangeable with single quotes like in R. Keep as is and wrap entire SQL in double quotes for an R variable and then escape any SQL double quotes with backslashes.

Comment: It's still something I'm not totally sure of, but the period between _SYS_BIC and the table name needs to be separated out by surrounding SYS_BIC and the table in double quotes, thus single quotes get used for the whole thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498890/issues-connecting-r-to-hana-db-with-many-special-characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider maintaining your working Tableau query with the integration of parameters in R with properly handling of double quotes for identifiers and single quotes for literals.

Additionally, parameterization is not supported with the old `('PLACEHOLDER'= ('<varname>', <varvalue>))` syntax.

Instead, as explained in [How to escape sql injection from HANA placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483948/how-to-escape-sql-injection-from-hana-placeholder) use the `PLACEHOLDER."<varname>" => ?` syntax.

```r
param1 <- 201943

sql <- "SELECT TOP 10 * 
        FROM \"_SYS_BIC\".\"ccf-edw.self-service.DOIP/R_CA_B_DemandPlan\"( 
             PLACEHOLDER.\"$$IP_ExtractionWeekFrom$$\", ?), 
             PLACEHOLDER.\"$$IP_ExtractionWeekTo$$\",?) 
        )\"_SYS_BIC\".\"ccf-edw.self-service.DOIP/R_CA_B_DemandPlan\" 
        WHERE (1 <> 0)"

SpringVisit <- dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, sql, param1, param1)
```

Additionally, if your JDBC already connects to the schema`_SYS_BIC`, use the [synonymous qualifier](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12365024/difference-between-abccalcview-and-sysbicabccalcvi.html) `::` as original query in order to reference package and calculation view:

```
sql <- "SELECT TOP 10 * 
        FROM \"ccf-edw.self-service.DOIP::R_CA_B_DemandPlan\"( 
             PLACEHOLDER.\"$$IP_ExtractionWeekFrom$$\", ?), 
             PLACEHOLDER.\"$$IP_ExtractionWeekTo$$\", ? ) 
        )\"ccf-edw.self-service.DOIP::R_CA_B_DemandPlan\" 
        WHERE (1 <> 0)"
```

Comment: Still getting syntax error in the first ````(SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "?": line 3 col 59 (at pos 148))````

That link is much appreciated, been wondering about that difference. Connected JDBC to the schema and also got the syntax near "?" error.

Comment: That is actually a different error. It appears you may not be able to parameterize. Try replacing `?` with actual numbers without params in `dbGetQuery` and see if query runs.

Comment: Yes! There we go. Thanks so much. New sql statement reads as ````sql <- "SELECT TOP 10 * 
        FROM \"ccf-edw.self-service.DOIP::R_CA_B_DemandPlan\"( 
            'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_ExtractionWeekFrom$$', '201943'), 
            'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_ExtractionWeekTo$$', '201943') 
        )\"ccf-edw.self-service.DOIP::R_CA_B_DemandPlan\" 
        WHERE (1 <> 0)"```` if you want to edit your response.

Comment: @jarichardson, please see edited solution as a SAP HANA expert shows parameterization is supported with newer placeholder syntax.